# why the new_list has to be put inside the for loop to prevent global change?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Would any one tell me the difference between these two blocks? I have hard time figuring out why the second one only changes the nested list locally, while the first changes it globally. it seems to me they do the same thing.

```
my_list = [ ] 
new_list = [0, 0, 0 ]## outside the loop
for index in range(5):
    my_list.append(new_list)
my_list[0][1] = 5
print(my_list)

## result
[[0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 5, 0]]


my_list = [ ] 
for index in range(5):
    new_list = [0, 0, 0 ] ## inside the loop
    my_list.append(new_list)
my_list[0][1] = 5
print(my_list)
## result
[[0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because inside the `for` loop, `new_list` get's *redefined*, effectively refering to a different list object for every iteration.

Printing the `id`s for the second case reveals this:

```
print(*map(id, my_list))  # Notice the different ids
140609203176456 140609194670088 140609194608840 140609212158216 140609194670152
```

Outside the loop, you append the same list object, *the same reference*. Changes will be visible througout all references.

Printing the `id`s for this case shows the same `id` (i.e, same list) is present:

```
print(*map(id, my_list))  # same id.
140609194670088 140609194670088 140609194670088 140609194670088 140609194670088
```